# Application Architecture For Ease of Application Customization

Tags: c#, events, plugins, customization

I'm looking for input on a direction to take for building an accounting application.  The application needs to allow for high customization, sometimes entire processes will need to changed.

I want a way to make changes without re-compiling the entire application when a customer has a specific modification request.  The back-end will be a SQL database of some sort.  Most likely SQL Server Express for cost reasons.  The front-end will be C#.

I'm thinking of an event-based system that will have events for when different types of actions, such as entries, are made.  I would then have a plugin system that handles the event.  I may need to have multiple processes apply in a specific order to the data before it is finally saved.  It will need to trigger other processes as well.

I want to keep my base application the same, which works for most customers, but have a graceful way of loading the custom processes that other specific customers have.

I'm open to all suggestions.  Even if they are thinking of completely different ways of approaching the problem.  Our current in-house development talent is .NET and MS SQL Server.  I'm not aware of a software pattern that may fit this situation.

Additional Info:
This isn't a completely blank slate system, it will have functionality that works for a large number of the customers.  For various reasons, requirements change based on states and even at the region and town level where customization may be necessary.

I'd like to be able to plugin additional pre-compiled modules.  When I started looking into possible options, I was imagining an empty handler that I could insert code into through a plugin.  So say for example, a new entry is made to the general ledger that raises an event.  The handler is called, but the handler's code is coming from a plugin, which may be my original process that fits 80% of the customers.  If a customer wants a custom operation, I could add a plugin that completely replaces the original one or have it add an additional post processing step through another plugin after the original runs.  Sort of a layering process I guess.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to compile? Are you saying you want to be able to plug in additional precompiled modules, or have everything driven by some sort of configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/)
It provide rich composition layer features that allow you to build loosely-coupled plugin applications.

Update : sound like you need the pre-defined modules on different geographic areas and using chain of responsibility design patern might help you manage the principle of change.
Sorry no codes provided just throwing my thoughts

Comment: I'm really liking this possibility.  Especially after finding that "Extensions themselves can depend on one another and MEF will make sure they are wired together in the correct order (another thing you won't have to worry about)."  It sounds very close to what I'm thinking would work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Workflow Foundation (WF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation) (part of the .NET Framework) is a potential candidate for your requirements. It enables various actions, command-lets and script-lets to be composed dynamically so that you can more easily customize different workflows for different users/customers.

WF is used by Biztalk for large-scale systems integration and is hosted in-process by many other applications that require the ability to easily modify the orchestration of a number of smaller tasks and actions.

You might want to start with [this tutorial on WF4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx).

HTH.

Comment: THat is limited - been there, done it. It is useless if your application does not support etending for example the UI (in a winform/wpf app) because you are limited to the forms already provided. But it is VERY good for flexible business logic.

Comment: I'd have to look closer at some examples.  It looks like it could have some possibilities.  It is reminding me of SQL Server Integration Services.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just plugins or the way how do you technically resolve that plugin problem, use MEF (+1 @laptop) or something else, You got to put most effort in defining plugin "points" in your application, this is gone be most important eg. where you will put that empty "events" to put your code, or what parameters this events or plugins will have.

For example usable plugin would be in before save event, but you will have to have only one place in application that will save various types of business documents, so you can call plugins there and parameter would be abstract document object.

So you have to think real hard about your system architecture, to be abstract enough for various plugin points, and do that architecture completely, don't do just a part of the system and start coding on that.

I hope that you understood what I meant to say, because English is not my native language.